# Problema ao listar produtos na Home Page do Magento 1.8

Tags: php, magento

Na loja Magento que estou criando, não consigo listar mais do que 9 produtos na página inicial. Creio que esse pode ser um problema com o tema, mas não consegui aumentar essa quantidade.

Loja: [donachicosa.com.br](http://donachicosa.com.br)

Alguém já teve esse problema?

O *XML* está em branco (não sei porque) e a loja já tem 25 produtos cadastrados. (Além de estar em branco, não achei qualquer outro XML que o sistema aceite)

Para listar os produtos, estou usando o seguinte trecho de código:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Ainda, para piorar, não vejo o "Anterior" e "Próximo" do tema, para que o visitante possa navegar pela paginação.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?